# PHP script, SQL insert error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a wamp server and created a series of html webpages the data being put in by the user is then being submitted to a SQL database through a PHP script. I created a database table with `Id. set to INT auto increment Crime. and Suspect. set as VARCHAR(40)`. I can connect to the database but now when I try to insert I get the error:

> 'Problem with insert: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case (Id, Case, Suspect) VALUES('NULL', 'test', 'test12')' at line 1'

So I know its an issue with the insert function however cannot fix it!

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db = 'fid';

$case = (isset($_POST['case'])? $_POST['case']:"None");
$suspect= (isset($_POST['suspect'])? $_POST['suspect']:"None");

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if (!$conn)
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO case 
(Id, Case, Suspect) VALUES('NULL', '$case', '$suspect') ") 
or die(' Problem with insert: ' . mysql_error());  
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). If you're going to have a table and columnj  named `case` you need to put it in ticks:

```
INSERT INTO `case` (Id, `Case`, Suspect) VALUES('NULL', '$case', '$suspect')
```

Also, 
[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Thank you for the help I've been going around in the circles for the past day trying to fix, just looked into PDO thanks for the suggestion!!